# Prove/disprove: Suppose R is a total order on A and $B \subseteq A$. Every element of $B$ is either the smallest element or the largest element

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

> Suppose $R$ is a total order on $A$ and $B \subseteq A$. Then every element of $B$ is either the smallest element of $B$ or the largest element of $B$

I believe that the proposition is incorrect.

My attempt at disproving it:

If there are more than $2$ elements in $B$, then it would imply that

1. either there are more than $2$ largest elements
2. or there are more than $2$ smallest elements

But we know that if there is smallest or largest element, it must be unique. Hence proposition is incorrect.

Will this explanation suffice?

Comment: It's a little bit hard for me to understand how this question could be asked.  Are you sure you are providing it correctly and there is no other condition?  Or was an argument given that the statement *should* be true and you had to find the error?  Because.... the statement seems absurd as it is.

Comment: @fleablood, I copied proposition from the book without making any changes. And I'm asked to prove/disprove this proposition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I see... an order has  antisymmettry that $a\le b$ and $b\le a$ only if $a= b$.  Thus a subset $B$ can only have one larg*est* or one small*est* element.

If we define "largest" as "$x$ is the largest element of $B$ if for all $y \in B$, $y \le x$" then there is nothing in the definition that the largest element is unique.

Anti-symmetry implies this though.  If $x$ is such that $y \le x$ for all $y\in B$ and $w$ is such that $y \le w$ for all $y\in B$, then $x \le w$ and $w \le x$.  By anti-symmetry that means $x=w$.

But... It's not clear they wanted that sort of argument.  If they had they should have *asked* for it.

If it were me I'd give your argument full credit (after scratching my head for ten minutes wondering why such a weird question was even asked in the first place).

.....

Of course being a total (rather than well) order also in no way implies a non-empty subset has any largest or smallest elements.  Example: $A = \mathbb R$ and $B = (0, 1)$ and  "$\le$" being "the usual".

Comment: This is a perfectly reasonable "prove/disprove" question to ask. The goal is to disprove it. At an entry level to the subject it isn't obvious what to do, as it wasn't to the OP.

Comment: Well, it's obviously not true as a set can have more than two elements.  It's bit like asking prove or disprove that every number is even or if $x< y$ then there is no number $z$ so that $x < z <y$.... I think it is a really *weird* question.

Answer (score 2):

To disprove this, you must produce a counterexample. An abstract argument can provide intuition, but it cannot be a proof. So you can pick a totally ordered set, say $A=\mathbb Z$, and let $B=\{0,1,2\}$. There is an element that is not the smallest or the largest.

You could also be fancier and pick a dense total order with a subset that has no smallest or largest element.

Comment: "To disprove this, you must produce a counterexample."  What? Of course you don't!   "An abstract argument can provide intuition, but it cannot be a proof." Of course it can!... The thing is an *example* can never be a proof that a thing is always true but a *counter-example* can be a proof that a thing not always true. But that doesn't mean you *must* provide a counter-example.  It just means if you *do* find a counter-example, you don't have to do *anything* else.